# How to sort and implode an array

Tags: php, implode

I have an array from a database select query that looks like this;

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [users] => Array ( [email] => makamo66@hotmail.com ) ) [1] => Array ( [users] => Array ( [email] => makamo66@gmail.com ) ) ) )
```

How do I just get the email addresses so that it looks like this:

```
makamo66@hotmail.com, makamo66@gmail.com
```

Comment: Show us what you tried first, and then we will help you to correct your script.

Comment: Your database can most likely do what you want; do you *need* to sort and implode in PHP, or would sorting/imploding in the database (and returning that to PHP) be okay for you?

Answer (score 2):

I've recreated you array structure for this example. I hope this will get you started.

```
<?php
    $all = array(
        array(
            array('users' => array('email' => 'makamo66@hotmail.com')),
            array('users' => array('email' => 'makamo77@hotmail.com'))
            )
        );
    $cleanarray = array();
    foreach ($all[0] as $key => $value) {
        array_push($cleanarray, $value['users']['email']);
    }
    $comma_separated = implode(",", $cleanarray);
    echo $comma_separated;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for a recursive array search there is one built into PHP now.

```
function itemTest_func($item,$key){
     if($key == 'email') array_push($item);
}

array_walk_recursive($Multi_level_array, 'itemTest_func');
```